# How to change values in one dropdown list change depending on the value in another dropdown list in aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have two dropdown boxes in aspx page. One for location and one for the vendor list.
I am fetching values in the dropdown list of location from this

```
 SELECT Location_ID LocationID, Location_Name LocationDesc, BusinessID
 FROM inventory.tbl_location
union 
SELECT '' LocationID,'select a location' LocationDesc,0 BusinessID
ORDER BY BusinessID,Location_Name
```

I am able to grab the list of all records in the vendor dropdown from this :

```
SELECT p.PayeeID, isnull(Name1_Last,'') + ',  ' + isnull(Name1_First,'') VendorName, b.BusinessID
from tblVendor_Payees p join tblVendor_Business b 
on p.PayeeID=b.PayeeID 
where VendorType=1
order by isnull(Name1_Last,'') + ',  ' + isnull(Name1_First,'')
```

I want to list only those vendor records based on the location dropdown. How to do that?.

Comment: You will need to join between tblContractTypes and one of the other tables you're selecting from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set up a dropdown list that is data bound to a separate select statement to get the vendor types.

your query would look something like this

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "
SELECT p.PayeeID, isnull(Name1_Last,'') + ',  ' + isnull(Name1_First,'') VendorName, b.BusinessID
from tblVendor_Payees p join tblVendor_Business b 
on p.PayeeID=b.PayeeID 
where VendorType= @vender 
order by isnull(Name1_Last,'') + ',  ' + isnull(Name1_First,'') "

cmd.Parameters.Add("@vender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = drop_down_list_vendor .Text;
```

Then all you have to do is built the drop down list the user selects vendor from.

Comment: i editied the question please look into it now...and change your answer please

Comment: based on the location of the control in the gridview? Like column(3) for example?